# Kafka multiple consumer groups different threads not working as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

So I am fairly familiar with Kafka and how consumer groups work, in that 2 consumers in different consumer groups that subscribe to the same topic should both get their own copy of the published messages on a Kafka Topic.

**consumer pre process**

This holds true when using 2 different processes for the 2 consumers. Where I can use this code for the producer

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Confluent.Kafka;
    using Confluent.Kafka.Admin;
    using NLog;

    namespace Producer
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Global");
            private static string topicName = "insane6";

            public static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                var config = new ProducerConfig
                {
                    Acks = Acks.Leader,
                    BootstrapServers = "XXXXXXXX"
                };

                using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = config.BootstrapServers }).Build())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        adminClient.CreateTopicsAsync(new TopicSpecification[] {
                            new TopicSpecification { Name = topicName, ReplicationFactor = 1, NumPartitions = 1 } }).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }
                    catch (CreateTopicsException e)
                    {
                        _logger.Error($"An error occured creating topic {e.Results[0].Topic}: {e.Results[0].Error.Reason}");
                    }
                }

                // If serializers are not specified, default serializers from
                // `Confluent.Kafka.Serializers` will be automatically used where
                // available. Note: by default strings are encoded as UTF8.
                using (var p = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config)
                    // Note: All handlers are called on the main .Consume thread.
                    .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => _logger.Error($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
                    .SetStatisticsHandler((_, json) => _logger.Debug($"Statistics: {json}"))
                    .SetLogHandler((consumer, message) => _logger.Debug($"{message.Level} {message.Message}"))
                    .Build())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Type 'Q' to quit");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            var dr = await p.ProduceAsync(topicName,
                                new Message<Null, string>
                                    { Value =DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O") });

                            _logger.Debug($"Delivered '{dr.Value}' to '{dr.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
                        }
                        catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e)
                        {
                            _logger.Error($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
                        }

                        var key = Console.ReadKey();
                        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have this consumer code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Confluent.Kafka;

    namespace Consumer
    {
        class Program
        {
            private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            private KafkaSubscriber kafkaSubscriber;
            private string topicName = "insane6";

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var p = new Program(args[0]);
           }


            public Program(string consumerGroup)
            {
                kafkaSubscriber = new KafkaSubscriber(new ConsumerSettings()
                {
                    ConsumerConfig = CreateConfig(consumerGroup),
                    Topic = topicName,
                    
                });
                kafkaSubscriber.ReceiveError += KafkaSubscriber_ReceiveError;
                kafkaSubscriber.CreateConsumer(cts.Token);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private void KafkaSubscriber_ReceiveError(object sender, System.IO.ErrorEventArgs e)
            {
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                kafkaSubscriber.CreateConsumer(cts.Token);
            }

            public ConsumerConfig CreateConfig(string consumerGroup)
            {
                var conf = new ConsumerConfig
                {
                    GroupId = consumerGroup,
                    BootstrapServers = "XXXXXX",
                    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
                    EnableAutoCommit = false,
                    ClientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
                    
                };
                return conf;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the actual subscriber code looks like this

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Confluent.Kafka;
    using NLog;

    namespace Consumer
    {
        class KafkaSubscriber
        {
            private readonly ConsumerSettings _consumerSettings;
            private static ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Global");

            public KafkaSubscriber(ConsumerSettings consumerSettings)
            {
                _consumerSettings = consumerSettings;
            }

            public event EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> ReceiveError;

            protected virtual void OnReceiveError(ErrorEventArgs e)
            {
                ReceiveError?.Invoke(this, e);
            }

            private void ErrorHandler(IConsumer<Ignore, string> consumer, Error error)
            {
                _logger.Error("Kafka ErrorHandler", error);
                if (error.IsFatal || error.Code == ErrorCode.Local_TimedOut)
                {
                    _logger.Error("Throwing fatal error code as exception");
                    throw new KafkaException(error);
                }
            }

            public void CreateConsumer(CancellationToken ct)
            {
                using (var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(_consumerSettings.ConsumerConfig)
                    .SetErrorHandler(ErrorHandler)
                    .SetStatisticsHandler((_, json) => _logger.Debug($"Statistics: {json}"))
                    .SetLogHandler((consumer, message) => _logger.Debug($"{message.Level} {message.Message}"))
                    .SetPartitionsAssignedHandler((c, partitions) =>
                    {
                        _logger.Info($"Assigned partitions: [{string.Join(", ", partitions)}]");
                        })
                    .SetPartitionsRevokedHandler((c, partitions) =>
                    {
                        _logger.Info($"Revoking assignment: [{string.Join(", ", partitions)}]");
                    })
                    .Build())
                {
                    c.Subscribe(_consumerSettings.Topic); 
                    //c.Assign();

                    try
                    {
                        var count = 0;
                        var offsets = new List<ConsumeResult<Ignore, string>>();
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var cr = c.Consume(ct);
                                c.Commit(cr);
                                _logger.Debug(
                                    $"\r\n{_consumerSettings.ConsumerConfig.GroupId} Consumed message '{cr.Message.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.\r\n");
                            }
                            catch (ConsumeException e)
                            {
                                _logger.Error($"Error occured: {e.Error.Reason}");
                                OnReceiveError(new ErrorEventArgs(e));
                            }
                            catch (InvalidProgramException e)
                            {
                                _logger.Error($"Error occured: {e.Message}");
                                OnReceiveError(new ErrorEventArgs(e));
                            }
                            catch (KafkaException kex)
                            {
                                _logger.Error($"Error occured: {kex.Message}");
                                OnReceiveError(new ErrorEventArgs(kex));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        c.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So if I run a single producer, and 2 consumer processes  (consumers run from command line like Consumer.exe "cg1" and Consumer.exe "cg2"

Everything works as expected, both consumers get the message from the publisher on the topic, as shown in the following screen shot

[image: consumer per process]

All good so far, but according to every other StackOverflow or Kafka doc I have seen it should be possible to have a consumer per thread.

**consumer pre thread**

So If I adjust my bootstrap consumer code to this, which should be identical to running the 2 separate processes, since each consumer is using a new consumer group name, each consumer is in its own thread, there really should be no difference to the 2 separate processes

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program(new [] { "cat","dog"});
    }

    public Program(string[] consumerGroups)
    {
        foreach (var consumerGroup in consumerGroups)
        {
            var thread = new Thread((x) =>
                {
                    kafkaSubscriber = new KafkaSubscriber(new ConsumerSettings()
                    {
                        ConsumerConfig = CreateConfig(consumerGroup),
                        Topic = topicName,


                    });
                    kafkaSubscriber.ReceiveError += KafkaSubscriber_ReceiveError;
                    kafkaSubscriber.CreateConsumer(cts.Token);
                });
            thread.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Yet when running this code, this is what is seen, where **only 1** of the consumers actually picks up a message from the topic, this is not the expected behavior at all for me.

[image: consumer per thread]

I really can't see anything weird, I don't think I have missed anything. All seems correct. Yet only 1 consumer "dog consumer group" in this case sees the produced topic messages, for me the "cat consumer group" should also see the produced messages.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using the Confluent.Kafka official C# driver : https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-dotnet/current/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Was being complete spanner, the consumer variable was not private to the thread, all ok now. Phew